# Best way to validate an upload form?

Tags: php

Which would be the best way to validate an upload form?

Using the mime type at the moment, but that's not quite working - can't upload mpegs even though am looking for `video` in the mime type.

Thank you

Tom

Comment: You means validate file type ?

Comment: yeah, sorry - so no-one can upload a php script and run it or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
switch (strtolower($_FILES["file"]["type"])){
        case "application/msword":
        case "application/pdf":
        case "application/vnd.ms-excel":
        case "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint":
        case "application/zip":
        case "image/gif":
        case "image/jpeg":
        case "image/png":
        case "image/tiff":
        case "text/plain":
        case "video/mpeg":
        case "video/x-mpeg2":
        case "video/msvideo":
        case "video/quicktime":
            // do it
            break;
        default:
            // don't do it
            break;
    }
```

For anyone else this might help have a look at http://www.sfsu.edu/training/mimetype.htm for adding other mime types you might need to check.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to check if an uploaded file is a valid video-file. So one thing you can check is the file extension (IE ".mpg" for mpeg video). Because no webframework known to me has an internal video-validation, you have to rely on some external program/library to check if the video file is really a video-file. Maybe [FFMPEG](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) is able to do this.

Comment: But then again using such a huge library as FFMPEG for a little script like this is "sick".

Answer (score 0):

Try something like so:

```
$mime = strtolower($_FILES["file"]["type"]);
$parts = explode("/",$mime);

switch($parts[0])
{
    case 'video':
        //Video file, use $parts[1] to check the video subtype
    break;
    case 'image':
    break;
}
```

Comment: that's what I had originally, but it didn't seem to work, not sure why, I think maybe it was because I didn't have `strtolower(...)` :)#